# How to solve the above differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{y}{x}$$

How to solve this differential equation? I know how to solve this because the ultimate way of solving this is $y\,dy=x\,dx$ and then integrating on both sides we will get $y^2/2=x^2/2 +c$. But my question is that why we don't put constants on both sides of the equation like I am trying to say that why the solution is not $y^2/2 + C =x^2/2 +c$? Why do we don't put constants on both sides?

Comment: What you say is correct but, if $\frac{y^2}{2}+C=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ where $C$ and $c$ are constants, then $\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+(c-C)$ where $c-C$ is a(nother) constant. In other words varying _two_ constants does not provide you with any different set of solutions than varying just one constant.

Comment: Yes you are correct@Stinking Bishop.

Comment: But my question is that why do we generally don't put constants on both sides?

Comment: Simplicity of course. Also the number of constants normally is equal to the number of known values you want to calculate if you want a *particular* solution, so that you can have a shot at finding a unique solution. Say, you know $y(0)=2$, this will let you calculate a single constant.

Comment: Personally, I'd multiply your form of solution by $2$ to get the equivalent solution $y^2=x^2+C$.  Do you see why my form of solution is equivalent to yours?

Comment: Remember, from the MVT, if $f' = g'$, then $f = g + C$ for some constant $C$. You could put additive constants on both sides, but they can be subsumed into one overall additive constant.

Comment: You stated the solution to be: $$ \frac{y^2}{2} + C = \frac{x^2}{2} + c $$ which we may rewrite as: $$ \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + c - C = \frac{x^2}{2} + K $$ and so having one constant on each side of the equation of your solution is equivalent to having one constant on one side of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that, but the next step would be to collect both arbitrary constants to one side of the equation. One arbitrary additive constant on one side is no more or less arbitrary that one on each side. So there is no loss of generality in just using one.

The value(s) of the constant(s) are determined by the initial conditions of the differential equation you are trying to solve. If you added two constants, you would see that one is determined by initial conditions and one is determined by the other constant. So two constants don't generalize your solution any further; they only encumber it.

Comment: But I can put constants on both sides also

Comment: @SUBHASANKARROY I added a paragraph about why there's no point in doing so.